# Find index of all columns which contain the max value of the row in R?

Tags: r

In order to find the max value of each row I used:

```
col_max <- apply(dat, max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

so I have a list of the max value for each row, but now I want to find the indices of each column where that max value appears by row (i.e., each row has a different max which may appear more than once).

How can I do this in R? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A little dput() of data goes a long way and allows future visitors to eyeball yours and evaluate how the answers might refer profitably to theirs.

Comment: check out `max.col`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible to simply use which.max() and then specify the column or row?
This is not the way you intended it, but it might be simpler?

Comment: I need the location of every occurrence of the max value in a row and which.max() returns only one (the first, last, or random)

Comment: which(data$columnname == max(data[,1])) maybe this is better? It still only works for the first column though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# data frame with 5 columns and 10 rows
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 50, replace = T), nrow = 10))
# name for rows
rownames(dat) <- letters[1:10]
# find the max positons by row
apply(dat, 1, function(x) which(x %in% max(x)))
# find the max positons by col
apply(dat, 2, function(x) which(x %in% max(x)))
```